# Kaluza suggested metric

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, metric-tensor, kaluza-klein

Is there a book or a paper that goes into the mathematical details of getting scalar curvature of the 5 dimensional metric that [Kaluza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) wrote down? I am running into many mathematical issues for I am not good with indices yet. I would like to understand this thoroughly for all books I read only wrote it down with no mathematical procedures at all! Your suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to start with the ADM formalism.  The details of the Kaluza-Klein seperation will be a little different, because they're foliating on a timelike fiber, and thus, your "special" dimension is spacelike, but the idea is essentially the same -- the lapse function is your dilaton field, and the shift is your vector potential.  I'm sure that there are other sources, but I know that I work through all of this in a lot of detail in my dissertation.  (I don't directly apply it to the Kaluza-Klein formalism there).

It would probably also be worth looking at Eric Poisson's **A Relativist's Toolkit**.

And I should also note that this isn't really a specific metric, so much as a way of splitting a general metric in the presence of a compactified dimension, with the result of getting an extra scalar field and an extra 4-vector which you could theoretically identify with the electromagnetic vector potential.